# Is it too much to ask to have an invisible button on jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I struggled with this for a while, so figured I'd put the answer on here.

How can I have an invisible button on jQM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the button using this tag -

`<input type="[yourchoice, mine was submit]" id="[yourchoice]" data-role="none" />`

The crucial part is the `data-role="none"`. This means jQM ignores it, so when you use `$.hide()`, you're not left with a random empty blob of rendering on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I can't receive click event on submit by pressing the "go" button if input is hidden (if it is not hidden - it works). I workaround it using css: "width:1px; height: 1px; background: transparent; border: 0;". May be it helps someone too.

Comment: apparently, it helps me :) thanks. This works especially if your form has only one text field.