# How can I leverage the 'Go' or 'Submit' button on a mobile software keyboard in a HTML5 app?

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

Mobile devices with software keyboards often change the keyboard when filling in a web form to allow the user to submit with one click and avoid jabbing at the 'submit' button of the form.

How can one access this functionality from a phonegap/cordova/other HTML5 app?

I struggled with this for a while, so gonna share the answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://blog.mattnunes.com/2012/02/ajax-form-submission-in-phonegap-using-the-soft-keyboard/#comment-253) blog post by Matt Nunes showed me that the `type="submit"` `input` should be the first button in the form.

Once you know this, you might be satisfied, but I wanted to hide the button - why have it when you want the user to use their keyboard? For an outline of how to do this, check out this related question - [Is it too much to ask to have an invisible button on jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174159/is-it-too-much-to-ask-to-have-an-invisible-button-on-jquery-mobile)

Effectively, when the user taps the 'go' button on their soft keyboard, it shows up to the browser as a `click` on the `submit` button. Therefore,

(1) Override the default event

(2) Profit.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: In my case I can't receive click event on submit by pressing the "go" button if input is hidden (if it is not hidden - it works). I workaround it using css: "width:1px; height: 1px; background: transparent; border: 0;". May be it helps someone too.

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not find blog.mattnunes.com

Did you mean: mattnunes.­com